# match line number of a 1d array with first element of a 2d array for large dataset in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, lookup

I've two large lists - here I will show just an example to simplify.

In **list1** I've some words,

```
list1 = ['hello','stack','overflow']
```

in **list2** I've the line number of the words of list1, and a numerical value to identify the type of word.

```
list2= [['0','10'],['2', '11'],['4', '12']]
```

I would like to use the line number of list2

```
list2 = [['0','10'],['2', '11'],['4', '12']] #line numbers here are: 0,2,4
```

with the corresponding line in list1,

```
list1 = ['hello','stack','overflow'] #correspondences found here are: hello (for list2[0]) and overflow (for list2[1])
```

so that I can have a list3 with word and its tag.

```
list3 = [['hello','10'], ['overflow', '11']]
```

I found a way to cross both lists but it's very slow and I think not efficient at all. How might I simplify this lookup process?

```
list1 = ['hello','stack','overflow']

list2= [['0','10'],['2', '11'],['4', '12']]


for i in range(0, len(list1)):
    for k in range(0, len(list2)):
        if (str(list2[k][0]) == str(i)):
            print("Found "+str(list1[i]))
```

> Found hello
> Found overflow

Comment: It seems like in your code you are using `i` as an index, so that when you are comparing that index to the `list2[k][0]`, you are actually getting overflow at a position of 2, but of type 11. I'm not sure this is what you desire based on your desired `list3`.

Comment: Why the output is `['overflow', '12']` shouldn't it be `['overflow', '11']`?

Comment: fixed @DaniMesejo  wrongly wrote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could do:

```
list1 = ['hello', 'stack', 'overflow']
list2 = [['0', '10'], ['2', '11'], ['4', '12']]

# transform the line numbers to ints
line_numbers = [(int(l), e) for l, e in list2]

# filter and compound with other number
res = [[list1[ln], other] for ln, other in line_numbers if ln < len(list1)]

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[['hello', '10'], ['overflow', '11']]
```